# Is there a way to write this in python more efficiently so that the runtime is less for an if-elif with product range calculating thresholds

Tags: python, if-statement

I am calculating accuracy scores by determining all possible combinations of thresholds and then using those thresholds to return the matched name, and then scoring each of those threshold combinations to see which returns the highest accuracy score. To do this, i created the possible combinations using product(range()) and then applied those with an if-elif statement, but it takes a very long time (so far over an hour to run on 1300 rows). Is there a better way?

Here is a sample of the df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name_Raw':['AECOM TECHNICAL SERVICES', 'AECOM_*', 'AECOM- Amentum', 'AECOM GOVERNMENT SERVICES (Inactive)', 'ADT LLC dba ADT Security Services', 'ADT', 'AAA Call Center', 'AAA of Northern California, Nevada', 'ANHEUSER BUSCH InBev'], 'Name_CleanCorrect':['AECOM', 'AECOM', 'AECOM', 'AECOM', 'ADT SECURITY CORPORATION', 'ADT SECURITY CORPORATION', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AB InBev'], 'Name_ngram':['AECOM', 'AECOM', 'AECOM', 'AECOM', 'ADT SECURITY CORPORATION', 'ADT SECURITY CORPORATION', 'AAA', 'State Bar of California', 'Ivanhoe Cambridge USA'], 'Score_ngrams':[38, 100, 51, 33, 52, 41, 36, 30, 16], 'Name_Fuzz':['AECOM', 'AECOM', 'AECOM', 'AECOM', 'ADT SECURITY CORPORATION', 'ADT SECURITY CORPORATION', 'AAA', 'State Bar of California', 'AB InBev'], 'Score_fuzz':[100, 100, 100, 100, 65, 85, 85, 37, 65], 'Name_jw':['Chicago Title Insuranc', 'Invesco', 'Heitman', 'Patheon/Thermo Fisher Scientific', 'Securitas Security Service', 'Michael Baker International, LLC', 'Bank of America', 'Ascension Health', 'Frontier Communication'], 'Score_jw':[66, 66, 63, 61, 62, 64, 67, 32, 100]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df2)
```

My current code:

```
from itertools import product

def f(x, ngram_thresh, cosine_thresh, fuzz_thresh, fuzz_rat_thresh, fuzz_prat_thresh, jaro_thresh, jw_thresh, jaccard_thresh, lev_thresh):
    if x['Score_ngrams'] >= ngram_thresh : return x['Name_ngram']
    elif x['Score_cosine_words'] >= cosine_thresh : return x['Name_cosine_words']
    elif x['Score_fuzz'] >= fuzz_thresh : return x['Name_fuzz']
    elif x['Score_fuzz_ratio'] >= fuzz_rat_thresh : return x['Name_fuzz_ratio']
    elif x['Score_fuzz_pratio'] >= fuzz_prat_thresh : return x['Name_fuzz_pratio']
    elif x['Score_jaro'] >= jaro_thresh : return x['Name_jaro']
    elif x['Score_jw'] >= jw_thresh : return x['Name_jw']
    elif x['Score_jaccard'] >= jaccard_thresh : return x['Name_jaccard']
    elif x['Score_lev_r'] >= lev_thresh : return x['Name_lev_r']
    else: return 0

for ngram_t, cosine_t, fuzz_t, fuzz_rat_t, fuzz_prat_t, jaro_t, jw_t, jaccard_t, lev_t in product(range(50,110,5), repeat=9):
    df_fourth[f'Name_Clean_{ngram_t}_{cosine_t}_{fuzz_t}_{fuzz_rat_t}_{fuzz_prat_t}_{jaro_t}_{jw_t}_{jaccard_t}_{lev_t}'] = df_fourth.apply(f, ngram_thresh=ngram_t, cosine_thresh=cosine_t, fuzz_thresh=fuzz_t, fuzz_rat_thresh=fuzz_rat_t, fuzz_prat_thresh=fuzz_prat_t, jaro_thresh=jaro_t, jw_thresh=jw_t, jaccard_thresh=jaccard_t, lev_thresh=lev_t, axis=1)
```

Comment: I think there is a way to write it more elegantly, but in terms of time optimizations it might just be that what you are doing takes a very long time. Is there any evidence that would suggest the `if elif` blocks are costing a lot? Also, what is `df_fourth`? In my opinion, more context and data is needed to help.

Comment: sure, df_fourth is my dataframe. I added a few of the columns as a sample, obviously it has all 9 methods a Name and a score as separate columns. okay its been two hours now. understand there are lots of potential thresholds combinations, but if 1,300 rows takes this long, can't imagine how long the real set of 200k will take.

Comment: `product(range(50,110,5), repeat=9)` will be 5 159 780 352 iterations, each of which will store something in `df_fourth` which is going to require at least 446.9 GiB of RAM in my estimations. The number of rows doesn't even factor into this as far as I can tell.

Comment: @bdubs88 if you plan on doing 200k rows then you probably need some other service like Hadoop and/or pyspark.

Comment: is there any better way to determine the optimum thresholds combinations for these?

Comment: I suppose i could separate each step since the highest score of all combined will be the threshold for each individual method that produces the highest score.

Comment: The function itself can be optimized but it is insufficient to solve your problem given the amount of computation needed. It seems to me that you are actually trying to build a decision tree (DT) with a particular shape. In this case, it might be better to actually train some DTs and evalutate their accuracy scores.